# What is equivalent of socket programming's select() in MPI?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed, distributed-computing

In socket programming, we have [select()](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/selectman.html) function which allows us to simultaneously check multiple sockets. I want to know is there any such feature available in MPI library as well?

In the first for loop of the following code, I am sending multiple nonblocking send and receive requests from one to every other node. In the second for loop instead of waiting for each node in sequential order, I want to start processing the data of the node which sends its data first.  I want to know is there any way to do that?

```
for(id=0; id<numtasks; id++){
        if(id == taskid) continue;
        if(sendCount[id] != 0) MPI_Isend(sendBuffer[id], N*sendCount[id], MPI_DOUBLE, id, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[id]);
        if(recvCount[id] != 0) MPI_Irecv(recvBuffer[id], N*recvCount[id], MPI_DOUBLE, id, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[id]);
}

for(id=0; id<numtasks; id++){
        if(id == taskid) continue;
        if(recvCount[id] != 0){
                MPI_Wait(&reqs[id], &status);
                for(i=0; i<recvCount[id]; i++)
                        splitData(N, recvBuffer[id] + N*i, U[toRecv[id][i]]);
        }
}
```

According to the given answers, I have tried to modify my code but I am still getting segmentation fault error during run time. Please help me to figure out the error.

```
for(id=0; id<numtasks; id++){
        if(id == taskid) continue;
        if(sendCount[id] != 0) MPI_Isend(sendBuffer[id], N*sendCount[id], MPI_DOUBLE, id, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[id]);
        if(recvCount[id] != 0) MPI_Irecv(recvBuffer[id], N*recvCount[id], MPI_DOUBLE, id, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[id]);
}

reqs[taskid] = reqs[numtasks-1];
for(i=0; i<numtasks-1; i++){
        MPI_Waitany(numtasks-1, reqs, &id, &status); 
        if(id == taskid) id = numtasks-1;
        for(i=0; i<recvCount[id]; i++)
                splitData(N, recvBuffer[id] + N*i, U[toRecv[id][i]]);
}
```

Comment: What about using [`MPI_Waitany()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Waitany.3.php) for example?

Comment: @Gilles Please check my edited question

Comment: Sorry but your code snippet is not clear enough for me to be more specific. What I can say though is that using the same request for both a send and a receive is a recipe for disaster. And you should probably set `reqs[id]` to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`after having used it, and check if `id` is `MPI_UNDEFINED` prior to use it in your `MPI_Waitany()` loop...

Comment: @Gilles Thanks a lot! It's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest equivalent would be [`MPI_Waitsome`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Waitany.3.php), you provide a list of requests and it returns as soon as at least one request is completed. However, there is no timeout as in `select`. There is also `MPI_Waitany`, `MPI_Waitall` as well as `MPI_Testany`, `MPI_Testall`, `MPI_Testsome`.

The `any` and `some` variants mainly differ in the way the interface informs you about one or multiple completed requests.

Edit: You need to use a separate requests for each operation, specifically the send and receive operations.

Comment: I didn't see that in the original question (because I didn't scroll right), you must use separate requests for send and receive. If it still fails on you please provide a [mcve].